# append all files of name johnsfiles.txt

Tags: batch-file, find, append

I would like to append all files named johnsfiles.txt on my c drive.

Thats every file with this name regardless of sub directorys

How do i achive this?

Comment: Please clarify your question, how do you want to to this? Are you using a programming language or script (e.g. Powershell) ?

Comment: Sory how stuipid of me i forgot to add the most important i would like to achive this with Batch.

Comment: One more thing, I think my answer below is incomplete: Do you want the result as below or are you looking for a merge of the content of all files into a new file?

Comment: No I have a particular file by the name of johns files in several locations on difrent computers  i would like to append all the files with that nameregardless of howmany or where they are found

Comment: Please update your question, I think you´re missing most of your requirements. For example you dont mention anything about different computers or I still don´t understand what you mean by "append all files". Do you want the content of all files to be merged into one single file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
dir /s /B johnsfiles.txt > index.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
del allofjohnsfiles.txt
for /R %%a in (johnsfiles.txt) do type %%a >> allofjohnsfiles.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

[@Ryan Bemrose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534507/append-all-files-of-name-johnsfiles-txt/6541777#6541777)'s solution is good in that it would produce the expected result (the merged contents of all the `johnsfiles.txt` files found). However it might also result in multiple error messages about missing files. The thing is, the `FOR /R` loop behaves differently depending on whether you specify a *mask* or an actual *name* in the brackets. In the former case it would only iterate over the files found, while in the latter case it would 'find' the specified file in all the folders in the branch, including those not actually containg the file. Seems like the name is perfectly ignored and the command simply iterates over all the subfolders.

That is a bit strange, and I couldn't overcome it otherwise than by using the output of the `DIR /S /B` command in the loop, like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
TYPE NUL >allofjohnsfiles.txt
FOR /F %%a IN ('DIR /S /B johnsfiles.txt') DO TYPE "%%a" >>allofjohnsfiles.txt
```